# How to store links for selected images from an Array to the localstorage

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to store selected images by storing their index in the array. Once the index of the selected images is saved, and the button (`get item` (with the `id` of "done") is clicked, I need to stringify the images selected in the array so to store them in the localstorage. Then I need to extract the data from the localstorage and convert it back to an object, write the selected images on the page, and import the selected images from the local storage on the page. 
The page should work if changes are made to the length of the array.

Also, I need to use the checkbox to select or deselect the item, but at the moment it's only working when I click on the image. Thank you! Please only javascript

```
   <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        img.selected {opacity:0.5;}
      </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="vegetable()">
       <button id="done" onclick="new()">get item </button>
       <div id="idmain"></div>
       <script>
         function new() { }
         var hey = [
            { item: "knife", fruit: "banana.png" },
            { item: "fork", fruit: "apple.png" },
            { item: "sword", fruit: "kiwi.jpg" },
            { item: "spoon", fruit: "mango.jpg" }
         ];

         function vegetable () {
           for (var i = 0; i < hey.length; i++) {
             var Img = document.createElement("img");
             Img.setAttribute("src", hey[i].fruit);
             Img.setAttribute("class", "posterImage");

             var Div = document.createElement("div");
             Div.setAttribute("class", "posterDiv");
             Img.addEventListener("click", function() {
               if (this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                  this.className = "posterImage unselected";
                  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = false;
               } else {
                  this.className = "posterImage selected";
                  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = true;
               } 
             }); 
             Div.appendChild(Img);
             var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
             newCheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
             Div.appendChild(newCheckbox);
             document.getElementById("idmain").appendChild(Div);
           }
         }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: localStorage has size restrictions. Why would you need to store whole images?

Comment: No, I don't want to store the whole image, only the url

Comment: OK I misunderstood what *"I need to stringify the images selected"* meant

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about where you are running into problems? It sounds like you already understand how to store the data - but perhaps not?